# Is there a way to prohibit the use of a class by value in c style variable arguments list?

Tags: c++, c

Accidential use of classes inside of c style typeless variable arguments list is a common error source.
Example:

```
class MyString {
    public:
    char *pChars;
    int Length;

    MyString(char *pChars) {
        this->pChars = pChars; 
        Length = strlen(pChars); 
        } };

int main() {
    MyString s1("Bla1"), s2("Bla2");
    printf("%s%s", s1, s2); // This does not but should give a compiler warning/error!
    return 0; }
```

The printf call there receives the two s objects by value. that means all of their members are simply memory copied. But they are interpreted a simple char pointers. Result is a runtime error of course.

I am not asking for a solution to this, but I would like to have something I could add to my class so that the compiler warns me about it or gives an error.

Already tried to declarate but not implement a copy constructor. But it seems that no copy constructor is called. :-(

Please just answer to the question in the title. I do not need a discusson of why you should not use printf or these variable arguments lists - know that.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: "I do not need a discusson of why you should not use printf or these variable arguments lists - know that." - What is wrong with printf?

Comment: @mathepic: I can see one thing "wrong" with `printf`: it can invoke UB if you pass custom types as parameters (like in the question), while `std::stream's` can deal with them gracefully. But when properly used, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Check your compiler documentation there should be a flag to get it to warn in that case. The g++ compiler warns whenever a non-POD class is passed as arguments to a function with variable arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Decent compilers (like gcc) check whether `printf` arguments match format specifiers in format string.

Just do not forget to add `-Wformat` or `-Wall` command line option.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Well, maybe visual C++ is no descent compiler?

Comment: @kaptnole they postponed on the decency, at least regarding the issue you're experiencing :) http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98899/compiler-should-warn-about-passing-objects-of-non-pod-types-to-the-ellipsis. 
I know you don't want to hear this but don't use printf see advices here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017489/should-i-use-printf-in-my-c-code

Comment: @celavek I would have accepted your comment as an answer if you would have posted it as one :-)

Comment: @kaptnole well ... tough luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Derive from [boost::noncopyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/utility.htm)

Comment: That's equivalent to Cătălin's answer, and has the same problem; it won't prevent passing through `...`, since that gives undefined behaviour, not a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Hide copy constructor and assignment operator (declare them private, no need to implement them). Or derive the class from boost::noncopyable (which has the same effect).Passing arguments by value determines the usage of the copy constructor.

Comment: Except this doesn't help because the instance is not passed by value, but rather some raw bytes are passed and then `reinterpret_cast` -ed to `const char*`. I don't think there is a language-level means to avoid the situation. You can only depend on the compiler warning (e.g "cannot pass non-POD object through ...")

Comment: Well the OP said in his question already that he played with the copy constructor. Do you think that also overloading the assignment operator will change the behavior? Is that a feature/bug of visual c++?