# How cout is more typesafe than printf()

Tags: c++, c, cout

I have read this at many places, but do not understand. Why it is said that cout is more type safe than printf(). Just because it does not required to write `%d %c %f` or it has some deeper meaning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because we explicitly pass format string suppose if I misspelled `%d` with `%f` then -- undefined behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [printf vs cout in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c)

Comment: Since you mention type safe, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781819/printf-vs-stdcout and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017489/should-i-use-printf-in-my-c-code and ...

Comment: `printf` is a `varadic function` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function which are notoriously not type safe.

Answer (score 10):

This is why:

```
printf("%s\n", 42); // this will clobber the stream
```

This will cause a buffer overflow – the compiler cannot generally check that the format string in the first argument of `printf` corresponds to the types of the subsequent arguments. It *could* do this in the above case – because the string is hard-coded – and some compilers do.<sup>1</sup> But in general the format string may be determined at runtime so the compiler cannot check its correctness.

---

<sup>1</sup> But these checks are special-cased to `printf`. If you wrote your own `myprintf` function with the same signature as `printf`, there would be *no way* to check for type safety since the signature uses ellipsis `...` which elides all type information inside the function.

Comment: GCC's `format` attribute can be used to apply the same checks to your own `myprintf` function

Comment: Your example will not cause buffer overflow!!! It will just print string address.

Answer (score 8):

The `printf` family functions are **variadic functions**, as all of them uses ellipsis `...` which means argument(s) of **any** type(s) can be passed to the function as far as `...` is concerned. There is **no restriction** by the compiler, as there is **no requirement** on the *types* of the arguments. The compiler cannot *impose* any type-safety rule as the ellipsis `...` allows ALL types. The function uses a *format* string to *assume* the argument type (even if there is a mismatch!!). The *format* string is read and interpreted at runtime, by which time the compiler **cannot** do anything if there is mismatch because the code is already compiled. So in this way, this is not type-safe. **By type-safe, we usually mean that the compiler is able check type consistency of the programs, by imposing rules on the types of (unevaluated) expressions.**

Note that if there is a mismatch (which the function cannot figure out!), the program enters into the undefined-behaviour zone, where the behavior of the program is not predictable and theoretically anything could happen.

You can extend the same logic to any variadic function functions such as `scanf` family.

Answer (score 3):

1. the type system guarantees correctness with `std::ostream` but not `printf`.
   Konrad's answer is one example, but something like

   ```
   printf("%ld\n", 7);
   ```

   is also broken (assuming `long` and `int` are different sizes on your system). It may even work with one build target and fail with another. Trying to print typedefs like `size_t` has the same problem.

   This is (somewhat) solved with the the diagnostic provided by some compilers, but that doesn't help with the second sense:
2. both type systems (the run-time type system used in the format string, and the compile-time system used in your code) cannot be kept in sync automatically. For example, `printf` interacts badly with templates:

   ```
   template <typename T> void print(T t) { printf("%d\n",t); }
   ```

   you can't make this correct for all types `T`- the best you can do is `static_cast<int>(t)` so it will fail to compile if T is not convertible to int. Compare

   ```
   template <typename T> void print(std::ostream& os, T t) { os << t << '\n'; }
   ```

   which selects the correct overload of `operator<<` for any `T` that has one.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, compilers can't check arguments from printf, don't even argument count, neither check if they are suited format string. They are "optimized" to do that work, but is a special case, and may fail.
Example:

```
printf("%s %d\n", 1, "two", 3);
```

This will compile (unless optimized compiler detects failure), and at runtime, printf will consider first argument (1) a string and second ("two") a integer. printf will not even notice that there is a third argument, neither will notice if there aren't enough arguments!

Using cout, compiler must choose specific operator<< for each variable you insert.
Example:

```
cout<<1<<"two"<<3<<endl;
```

Compiler must change this in calls to corresponding `ostream&operator<<(int)` and `ostream&operator<<(const char*)` (and also `ostream&operator<<(ios&(*)(ios&))`).

cout will also be faster, as there is no runtime interpretation of format string.

Answer (score 1):

From the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/iostream-vs-stdio.html) :

> **[15.1] Why should I use `<iostream>`  instead of the traditional `<cstdio>`?**
>
> [...]
>
> More type-safe: With , the type of object being I/O'd is known statically by the compiler. In contrast,  uses "%" fields to figure out the types dynamically.
>
> [...]

For `printf`, the compiler cannot check that the format script of the first argument corresponds to the types of the other arguments... **In general it is done at runtime.**